# How to determine Weak and Strong verbs in Old English (Anglo-Saxon)

Tags: verbs, old-english, strong-verbs

How to determine whether a verb is a **weak verb** or a **strong verb** in Old English ?

Comment: You can look up this information in certain dictionaries ... do you mean to ask how to determine this based on some aspect of the word's form or meaning?

Comment: Weak verbs are propped up by a dental suffix; stong verbs have a vowel change. Just as in Present Day English, though they're mostly called irregular today.

Comment: @sumelic Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, KarlG wrote:

> Weak verbs are propped up by a dental suffix; strong verbs have a vowel change. Just as in Present Day English, though they're mostly called irregular today.